# Simple Goto problem

Tags: procedural-programming

```
In[1] Goto["place2"]; Label["place1"]; Return[10]; Label["place2"]; Return[20];

Out[1] Return[20]

In[2] f[x_] := (Goto[x]; Label["place1"]; Return[10]; Label["place2"]; Return[20];)

In[3] f["place2"]

Out[3] 20
```

Q1) Can you tell me why Out[1] is Return[20], not 20 ?

Q2) How to modify In[1] as slightly as possible, so that Out[1] becomes 20 ?

Comment: Thank you the comment is not related to my question but I learned something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, why on earth do you want to use [`Goto`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Goto)??

But, if you must, the problem you're encountering is that [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return) typically returns from a control structure (e.g., [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If)), and your example has none. When there is no control structure, the [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return) wrapper doesn't get stripped. To fix things, you can use the undocumented 2-arg form of [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return) (specifying [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression) in this case, becase that is the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) of `a; b; c`):

```
Goto["place2"]; Label["place1"]; Return[10]; Label["place2"]; Return[20,CompoundExpression];
```

> 20

Comment: Boy... Q:  "I want to use a screwdriver to eat my soup."  A:  "Why on earth do you want to do that??  Well, if you must..."

Comment: Thank you. I think it is hard to 'output something with exit' with goto.

Answer (score 0):

I think in mathematica,
when **dealing with** `Goto` command,
to make any final output on the screen,
following **4 things are necessary**.

1. create a final variable
2. create a way-out
3. assign a value for the final variable
4. go to the way-out

In the below example, 1),2),3),4) are EndValue,"End",Endvalue=10 or 20,Goto["End"], respectively.

```
Goto["place1"]; Label["place1"]; EndValue = 10; Goto["End"];Label["place2"]; EndValue = 20; Goto["End"]; Label["End"]; EndValue
```

Also there is other method like using `Return[something, CompoundExpression]` as Carol answered.